# How hard is counting the number of simple paths between two nodes in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs

There is an easy polynomial algorithm to decide whether there is a path between two nodes in a directed graph (just do a routine graph traversal with, say, depth-first-search).

However it seems that, surprisingly, the problem gets much harder if instead of testing for the existence we want want to *count* the number of paths.

If we allow paths to reuse vertices then there is a dynamic programming solution to find the number of paths from *s* to *t* with *n* edges. **However, if we only allow simple paths, that don't reuse vertices, the only solution I can think of is brute force enumeration of the paths**, something that has exponential time complexity.

So I ask,

- Is counting the number of simple paths between two vertices hard?
- If so, is it kind of NP-complete? (I say kind of because it is technically not a decision problem...)
- Are there other problems in P that have a hard counting versions like that too?**

Comment: BTW, I actually know the answer to this question now but I am curious about what kind of answer I would get if I asked it back when I first came up with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713508/find-the-paths-between-two-given-nodes

Comment: @Suresh: I know how to code the brute force search. My question if whether there is a more efficient algorithm. In any case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569256) SO question would be more similar, and even includes an answer of mine, if you are interested in spoilers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most common complexity class associated to counting problems is [#P](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Symbols#sharpp). Deciding if there a simple path from a given node to another is clearly in NP. Counting them is then in #P.

About the NP-completeness: even if that's not a decision problem, it would hardly fit in NP: there may be $n!$ paths, and non-determinism does not help you about that (you'd still need to check them all)

The answer to your two first two question is: yes, it is hard, [it is #P-complete (ref)](http://www.cs.brown.edu/sites/jgaa/accepted/2007/RobertsKroese2007.11.1.pdf).

The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete) gives pertinent facts: 1) probabilistic algorithms are useful to approximate #P-complete functions, and that's the kind of algorithm used for the approximation in the previous article. 2) There are other easy problems with hard (#P-complete) counting versions:

- finding (linear) vs. counting all assignments satisfying a [DNF formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) or an instance of [2-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability)
- finding (linear) vs. counting topological sortings
- finding (O(VE)) vs. counting perfect matching in bipartite graphs

You already know that if you remove the constraint "simple path" the problem falls into P (well you have to bound the length of the paths by a polynomial of the size of the graph or give the bound in unary)