# Optimization version of decision problems

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, search-problem, decision-problem

It is known that each optimization/search problem has an equivalent decision problem. For example the shortest path problem

> - **optimization/search version:**
>     Given an undirected unweighted graph $G = (V, E)$ and two vertices $v,u\in V$, find a shortest path between $v$ and $u$.
> - **decision version:** 
>     Given an undirected unweighted graph $G = (V, E)$, two vertices $v,u\in V$, and a non-negative integer $k$, is there a path in $G$ between $u$ and $v$ whose length is at most $k$?

In general, "Find $x^*\in X$ s.t. $f(x^*) = \min\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$!" becomes "Is there $x\in X$ s.t. $f(x) \leq k$?".

But is the reverse also true, i.e. is there an equivalent optimization problem for every decision problem? If not, what is an example of a decision problem that has no equivalent optimization problem?

Comment: Is this bit equal to zero?

Comment: You have to explain "equivalent" in more detail, e.g. do you mean one can be solved using the other as an oracle/blackbox in polynomial time (or in logarithmic space)? Do you care about all problems or only problems inside $\sf{NP}$?

Comment: Depending on your viewpoint, the question is either trivial (take any decision problem that does not have a "$k$") or not answerable (how to prove that there "no equivalent opt. problem"?).

Answer (score 33):

As already stated in the comments, it depends on the definitions, as usual. My attempt to answer this needs quite a few definitions, so this will be another example of my inability to give concise answers.

---

**Definition:** An *optimization problem* is a tuple $(X,F,Z,\odot)$ with

- $X$ the set of suitably encoded (strings) *instances* or *inputs*.
- $F$ is a function that maps each instance $x\in X$ to a set $F(x)$ of *feasible solutions* of $x$.
- $Z$ is the objective function that maps each pair $(x, y)$, where $x \in X$ and $y\in F(x)$, to a real number $Z(x, y)$ called the *value* of $y$.
- $\odot$ is the *optimization direction*, either $\min$ or $\max$.

**Definition:** An *optimal solution* of an instance $x\in X$ of an optimization problem $P_O$ is a feasible solution $y\in F(x)$ for which $Z(x, y)=\odot\{Z(x, y')\mid y'\in F(x)\}$. The value of an optimal solution is denoted with $Opt(x)$ and called the *optimum*.

**Definition:** The *evaluation problem*, denoted $P_E$, corresponding to the optimization problem $P_O$ is the following: Given an instance $x\in X$, compute $Opt(x)$ if $x$ has an optimal solution and output “no optimal solution” otherwise.

Note that this just asks for the *value* of the optimal solution not the whole solution itself with all its details.

**Definition:** The *decision problem*, denoted $P_D$ corresponding to the optimization problem $P_O$ is the following: Given a pair $(x, k)$, where $x\in X$ and $k\in\mathbb{Q}$, decide whether $x$ has a feasible solution $y$ such that $Z(x, y)\le k$ if $\odot=\min$ and such that $Z(x, y)\ge k$ if $\odot=\max$.

A first observation is now that $P_O\in \mathrm{NPO} \Rightarrow P_D\in \mathrm{NP}$. The proof is not difficult and omitted here.

Now intuitively $P_E$ and $P_D$ corresponding to $P_O$ are not more difficult than $P_O$ itself. To express this feeling formally (thereby defining what *equivalent* is supposed to mean) we will use reductions.

Recall that a language $L_1$ is polynomial-time reducible to another language $L_2$ if there is a function $f$, computable in polynomial time, such that for all words $x$, $x\in L_1\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in L_2$. This kind of reducibility is known as *Karp* or *many-to-one reducibility*, and if $L_1$  is reducible to $L_2$ in this manner, we express this by writing $L_1\le_m L_2$. This is a central concept in the definition of NP-completness.

Unfortunately, many-to-one reductions go between languages and it is not clear how to employ them in the context of optimization problems. Therefore we need to consider a different kind of reducibility, *Turing reducibility*. First we need this:

**Definition:** An *oracle* for a problem $P$ is a (hypothetical) subroutine that can solve instances of $P$ in constant time.

**Definition:** A problem $P_1$ is polynomial-time *Turing-reducible* to a problem $P_2$, written $P_1\le_T P_2$, if instances of $P_1$ can be solved in polynomial time by an algorithm with access to an oracle for $P_2$.

Informally, just as with $\le_m$, the relation $P_1\le_T P_2$ expresses, that $P_1$ is no more difficult than $P_2$. It is also easy to see that if $P_2$ can be solved in polynomial time, so can $P_1$. Again $\le_T$ is a transitive relation. The following fact is obvious:

Let $P_O\in \mathrm{NPO}$, then $P_D\le_T P_E\le_T P_O$.

Because given the full solution, computing its value and deciding whether it meets the bound $k$ is simple.

**Definition:** If for two problems $P_1$ and $P_2$ both relations $P_1\le_T P_2$, $P_2\le P_1$ hold, we write $P_1\equiv_T P_2$; our notion of *equivalence*.

We are now ready to proof that $P_D\equiv_T P_E$ given the corresponding optimization problem is $P_O\in \mathrm{NPO}$ and $Z$ is integer valued. We have to show that $P_E \le_T P_D$ holds. We can determine $\odot\{Z(x,y)\mid y\in F(x)\}$ with a binary search usign the orcale for $P_D$. The [definition of $\mathrm{NPO}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/473/decision-problems-vs-real-problems-that-arent-yes-or-no/476#476) ensures that $|Z(x, y)|\le 2^{q(|x|)}$ for some polynomial $q$, so the number of steps in the binary search is polynomial in $|x|$. $\Box$

For an optimization problem $P_O$ the relation to $P_E$ is less clear. In many concrete cases, one can show directly that $P_D\equiv_T P_E \equiv_T P_O$. To prove that this holds generally within the framework given here we need an additional assumption.

First we need to extend $\le_m$ from pairs of languages to pairs of the corresponding  decision problems. Then it is easy to see that $\le_T$ is more general than $\le_m$.

Let $P$ and $P'$ be decision problems; then $P\le_m P' \Rightarrow P\le_T P'$. This holds because a many-to-one reduction can be interpreted as making use of an oracle in a very restricted way: The oracle is called once, at the very end, and its result is also returned as the overall result. $\Box$

Now we are ready for the finale:

Let $P_O\in \mathrm{NPO}$ and suppose $Z$ is integer-valued and that $P_D$ is NP-complete, then $$P_D\equiv_T P_E \equiv_T P_O.$$ With the previous observations it remains to show $P_O\le_T P_E$. To do this we will exhibit a problem $P_O'\in \mathrm{NPO}$ such that $P_O\le_T P_E'$. Then we have $$P_O\le_T P_E' \le_T P_D'\le_T P_D\le_T P_E.$$ The second and third $\le_T$ hold because of the equivalence of the decision and evaluation version proofed earlier. The third $\le_T$ follows from the NP-completness of $P_D$ and the two facts mentioned before, namely $P_O\in \mathrm{NPO} \Rightarrow P_D\in \mathrm{NP}$ and $P\le_m P_O' \Rightarrow P\le_T P_O'$.

Now the details: Assume that the feasible solutions of $P_O$ are encoded using an alphabet $\Sigma$ equipped with a total order. Let $w_0, w_1, \ldots$ be the words from $\Sigma^*$ listed in order of nondecreasing length and lexicographic order within the blocks of words with common length. (Thus $w_0$ is the empty word.)  For all $y\in\Sigma^*$ let $\sigma(y)$ denote the unique integer $i$ such that $y=w_i$. Both $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ can be computed in polynomial time. Let $q$ be a polynomial such that for all $x\in X$ and all $y\in F(x)$ we have $\sigma(y)<2^{q(|x|)}$.

Now the problem $P_O'$ is identical to $P_O$ except for a modified objective function $Z'$. For $x\in X$ and $y\in F(x)$ we take $Z'(x, y)=2^{q(|x|)}\cdot Z(x,y)+\sigma(y)$.  $Z'$ is computable in polynomial time thus $P_O'\in \mathrm{NPO}$.

To show that $P_O\le_T P_E'$ we observe that $x$ is feasible for $P_O$ if and only if it is feasible for $P_E'$. We can assume that this is the case, since the opposite case is trivial to handle.

The substituion of $Z'$ for $Z$ is monotonic in the sense that for all $y_1, y_2\in F(x)$, if $Z(x, y_1)<Z(x, y_2)$ then $Z'(x, y_1)<Z'(x, y_2)$. This implies that every optimal solution for $x$ in $P_O'$ is an optimal solution of $x$ in $P_O$. Thus our task reduces to the computation of an optimal solution $y$ of $x$ in $P_O'$.

Querying the oracle for $P_E'$ we can get the value of $Z'(x,y)=2^{q(|x|)}\cdot Z(x,y)+\sigma(y)$. Forming the remainder of this number modulo $2^{q(|x|)}$ yields $\sigma(y)$ from which $y$ can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: "An oracle for a problem P is a (hypothetical) subroutine that can solve instances of P in constant time." Must an oracle take only constant time?

Comment: @Tim Of course there are books, I listed a few in the comments of another [answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/982/np-complete-optimization-problems/989#comment8185_989)

Comment: @Tim Regarding the oracle: If you have found/conceived a reduction $A\le_T B$ between two problems $A$ and $B$ you have *reduced* the problem of finding an efficient algorithm for $A$ to finding an efficient algorithm for $B$. Or in other words the reduction tells you that in order to solve $A$ you can use $B$. It is like using a subroutine for $B$ in an algorithm for $A$. However the problems $A$ and $B$ are often problems where we don’t know efficient solutions. And in case of Turing-reducibility we even use it in cases where the problems involved aren’t decidable at all.

Comment: @Tim Thus $B$ is an unknown subroutine. It has become a custom in complexity theory to call the hypothetical algorithm for $A$ derived from the reduction as an *algorithm with oracle $B$*. Calling the unknown subroutine for $B$ an oracle just expresses that we can’t hope to find an efficient algorithm for $B$ just as we can’t hope to obtain an oracle for $B$. This choice is somewhat unfortunate, as it connotes a magical ability. The cost for the oracle should be $|x|$ as a subroutine has at least to read the input $x$.

Comment: @Tim In case we find an efficient algorithm for $B$ with runtime $p$ we could replace the oracle with the algorithm and the total cost $p(|x|)$ would still be polynomial. If we choose the cost to be $1$ instead of $|x|$ all that we do is that we make an unknown subroutine a little bit more powerful. A turing machine with an oracle can decide more languages than an ordinary one.

Comment: An excellent answer all around; the only thing I would add (coming at it now via another question) is that the 'optimization direction' is a needless bit of complexity and for concreteness we can always presume that the objective function $Z$ is to be maximized; if the intention is to minimize, then we can just define a new objective function $Z'=-Z$ and rewrite all the minimization of $Z$ as maximization of $Z'$.

Answer (score 5):

As the comments say, the answer depends on the exact definitions.
Let me interpret the question in a very basic (even naïve) way.

Let $S$ be some relation, that is $S \subseteq \{ (a,b) \mid a,b \in \Sigma^*\}$.

Now we define a **search problem** for $S$:

> Given $a$, find a $b$ such that $(a,b) \in S$.

and a **decision problem** for $S$:

> Given $(a,b)$ answer whether or not $(a,b) \in S$.

<sub>(for instance, in the example given in the question, $S$ will hold all the pairs $(u,v,k)$  such that there exists a path between $u$ and $v$ which is shorter than $k$.)</sub>

Note that these two problems are **well defined**.
*For this definition*, we can ask whether the two problems are "equivalent" for any $S$. In "equivalent" I mean that if one of them is computable (i.e., there exists an algorithm that solves it) than the other one is computable as well. In general, they are not.

**Claim 1**: *Decision* implies *Search*.

Proof: Let $D_S$ be the algorithm that solves the decision problem of $S$. 
Given an input $a$, We can run $D_S(a,x)$ for any $x\in \Sigma^*$, one after the other, or in parallel. If there exists $b$ such that $(a,b)\in S$, we will eventually find it. If not, the algorithm might not stop$^\dagger$.

**Claim 2**: *Search* does **not** imply *Decision*.

The reason is that the search algorithm might return a different $b$ than the one we need. That is, for every $a$ there is some $b$ that is very easy to find, but other $b'$ that is not. 
For instance, let $L$ be some undecidable language, then define 
$$S = \{ (x,0) \mid x\in \Sigma^*\} \cup \{ (x,1) \mid x \in L\}.$$
For every $x$ the search algorithm can return $0$. But no decision algorithm can answer correctly whether $(x,1) \in S$, for *all* the pairs $(x,1)$. If it could, it would have decided an undecidable problem, which is impossible.

$^\dagger$ This depends on $S$. If, for instance, $S$ is bounded, there might exists an algorithm that does stop.

Comment: The right decision problem is existence of $b$ s.t. $\langle a,b \rangle \in S$.

Comment: If decision is defined as the existence of $b$, then search implies decision.

Comment: In a weak sense, i.e. w.r.t. computability but not complexity is a more delicate issue.