# Reframing decision, counting, enumeration, and search as optimization

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization

The top accepted answers to the questions below allude to two complexity classes of **optimization** problems:  **NPO** and **PO** (in relation to NP and P for **decision** problems):

- [Decision problems vs "real" problems that aren't yes-or-no](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/476/325)
- [Optimization version of decision problems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/943/116761)
- [“NP-complete” optimization problems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/989/325)

The way these questions and answers are written, I get the impression that many problems such as **counting**, **enumeration**, or **searching** problems could be framed as general **optimization problems** even if their formulation does **not** have an explicit **objective function** (i.e. [mathematical programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) problems). Is that correct?

Take decision problems for example, one often casts decisions in machine learning (ML) as those that ***minimize regret***, or e.g. an expected error in the evaluation against a loss function (e.g. 0/1 for decision problems).

These types of decisions or **search as-optimization** formulations for a wide variety of problems are fairly ubiquitous in ML.

Take some other common examples:

- Find the $n$th [Fibonacci term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence)
- Find the [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of a set of numbers
- Enumerate the subsets for which [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) answers "Yes"
- Count all hamiltonian cycles in a graph
- etc.

Couldn't one *easily* reframe many of them as optimization problems using a loss function as well? e.g. $\text{argmin}_x f(x)$, where $f$ is a measure of error defined on the solution space of the desired problem? Or is that reduction, despite its prevalence in e.g. ML, not always "easy", feasible or useful?

More generally, how does the ***family*** of complexity classes (and their associated types of reductions and definitions) for **search**, **enumeration** and **counting** relate to the family of their "reduction-equivalent" **optimization** problems?

Comment: With "ML" you are referring to [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) right?

Comment: Thanks @uli. Sorry I wasn't clear. I was referring to machine learning. I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Ah, all the young folks messing with the established abbreviations ....

Comment: You can add an objective function to sorting so that the sorted sequence gets min cost/max points and then interpret the problem of sorting a sequence as the optimization problem of finding the sequence with min cost/max points (the sorted one). That just makes things more complicated. My guess for sorting is that the objective function should not be too hard to find. I guess it would fit on a single sheet of paper. But for anything more involved the objective function is most likely not "simple", "linear", has a closed form and fits on one sheet of paper.

Comment: And constructing the objective functions in general or perhaps even automatically is probably a whole other matter. Take for example linear programming. If you are a carpenter or a tailor and want to solve the [cutting-stock-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) via linear programming. You have to come up with the concrete objective function for the linear programm for your scenario to limit the waste of material. This is an art in itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Search problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem) are in NP [if you can verify a solution in polynomial time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755).

[Counting problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_problem_(complexity)) are [♯P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP) if you're counting the number of solutions to an NP search problem.

Enumeration problems are not particularly special.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_problem.

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't one reframe these problems as optimization problems using a loss function? e.g. $\text{argmin}_x f(x)$, where f is a measure of error defined against the result of the desired problem. In other words, couldn't one argue that (many?) non-optimization problems are "easily" reducible to optimization problems? Or is that not always feasible?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina, yes for search problems, no for counting problems.  Yes many problems are reducible to optimization problems, which is not the same as saying they *are* an optimization problem.

Comment: Thanks. Why yes for search but not for counting problems?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina, I don't know how to give a "why".  I don't see how to usefully express a counting problem in that form.