# NP-Hard problems which are not NP-Complete

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, np-complete, np-hard, decision-problem

1. Is it always true that a problem which is ${\sf NP}$-hard but not ${\sf NP}$-complete is an optimization problem such as **Minimum-Vertex-Cover** and many others.
2. Is it always true that a ${\sf NP}$-complete problem is always a decision problem such as vertex cover of size $k$, independent set of size $k$ and many others.

Answer (score 10):

1. No. E.g. the Halting problem is a decision problem which is NP-hard but not in NP and therefore not NP-complete.
2. In normal usage yes, because an NP-complete problem must be in NP and NP is a class of decision problems. But see [Decision problems vs “real” problems that aren't yes-or-no](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/476/703).

Comment: Also [this one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/939/optimization-version-of-decision-problems).