# What is the Certificate for Set Cover?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization

Consider the set cover problem: given a collection of sets ${\cal U}$ whose elements come from $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ find the smallest number of sets in ${\cal U}$ whose union is all of $\{1, \ldots, m\}$. My question is: what would be a certificate for this problem? That is, if I wanted to convince someone that it is not possible to do this with fewer than $k$ sets, what information could I provide that would allow someone to verify that this is the case in polynomial time?

Answer (score 6):

The set cover is not a decision problem, so it doesn't necessarily have a certificate.  Rather, it is an optimization problem.

To make it a problem in NP (a decision problem, with a certificate), you need to apply the standard trick to convert an optimization problem to a decision problem: introduce a budget.  Thus, the decision budget is: given a collection of sets and an integer $k$, determine whether there exists a subset of $\le k$ sets whose union is all of $\{1,\dots,m\}$.  That *is* a decision procedure, and *does* have a certificate: the subset of size $k$ is the certificate.

See also [Optimization version of decision problems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/939/755) and standard textbooks.

Comment: Thank you! I notice you said "doesn't _necessarily_" have a certificate. So is it nevertheless possible that set cover (the optimization version of it, that is) does have a certificate?

Comment: @PeteV., There's no certificate for it, unless NP = co-NP (which is unlikely)... I think.

Comment: @D.W. That seems reasonable. Certainly, if NP=co-NP, there is a certificate: a cover of size $m$ plus a certificate that there is no cover of size $m-1$. Though, of course, your claim is the converse.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, here's my reasoning.  Consider the decision problem "Does this family of sets have a set cover using $\le k$ sets?".  This is in NP.  If we had a certificate for Pete V.'s optimization problem, we could use it as a certificate to prove the answer to this decision problem is "no".  That means this decision problem is in co-NP.  But this decision problem is NP-complete.  If a NP-complete problem is in co-NP, then NP = co-NP.