# Is it possible to do reductions with non-decision problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, optimization

I've recently begun studying reductions in my algorithms class. All the reductions I've seen have been from decision problem $\to$ decision problem.

Is it possible to do reductions with non-decision problems? 
Can NP-hardness be shown in that way?

Comment: Of course you can! You need another notion of reduction, of course. *Any* reduction defines its own notion of completeness.

Comment: [Another related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/473/decision-problems-vs-real-problems-that-arent-yes-or-no).

Comment: how do you think people knew puzzle like candy crush, tetris and minesweeper were NP complete in the first place? (that's my cool way of telling you to look up these papers!)