# Is maximising (or minimising) something enough to say that I am solving a decision problem?

Tags: terminology, optimization, decision-problem

We know that every optimisation problem has an equivalent decision problem.

So say I keep going up a mountain (I.e. I am maximising my altitude) following a certain number of finite steps (similarly to a TM). Is that enough to assert that I am solving a decision problem?

If yes which one?

Comment: [Also related](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/473/decision-problems-vs-real-problems-that-arent-yes-or-no).

Comment: And not, stating a maximization problem and calling it decision problem doesn't make it one.

Comment: @Raphael Well let me give you my version. In my example I am maximising my altitude by synthetically checking where my next step can lead me. Once that's done I take the step which produces the largest positive change in altitude. That's a decision problem and it looks like I can generalise this process leading me to believe that **indeed** every optimisation problem can be seen as a decision problems like shown by CS theory. Anything wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: You are not using "decision problem" in the way we do in TCS. We don't mean "decide where to go" but "decide between yes and no".

Comment: @Raphael I am. I am searching for the maximum altitude using a yes/no method