# Count of all simple paths between two vertices in a Complete graph

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

A path is simple if no vertices are repeated. How many simple paths exist between two vertices in a complete graph?

One way is listing all simple paths using depth-first search. but I think it should be more simple to find the number of all simple paths between 2 nodes in a complete graph.

Here is the same problem but mine is for a complete graph:
[Algorithm that finds the number of simple paths from $s$ to $t$ in $G$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/algorithm-that-finds-the-number-of-simple-paths-from-s-to-t-in-g)

Comment: $countOfAllpathInClique(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{k!}{2} = \Omega(2^n)$ 

$countPathBetween2vertices=countOfAllpathInClique(n-2)+2*(n-1)-1$

because we can assume we have a (n-2)clique + 2 other vertices.
so after we computed the all path of (n-2)clique we should add 2*(n-1) new edge and one of them is not new.

I'm not sure about the correctness of this.

Comment: Your question already contains what you claim to be an answer so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm Asking : How many simple paths between two vertices in n-clique?

Comment: How is this different from "how many s-t-paths are there in the complete graph"? Also, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I won't to compute the complexity of my algorithm,so i need the size of simple paths between two vertices.

Comment: i have an error in the title: i want the number of path from 2 vertexes in a Complement graph

Comment: Neither the body of the question nor your answer fits the modified title.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I edited the body of my question :)

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes, They was because of my bad English. I mean Complete Graph and i fixed it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c(1)=0,$

$c(n)=(n-2)*c(n-1)+1$

suppose we have c(n-1) path in (n-1)-Complete Graph.
when we add one more vertices, we add $(n-2)*c(n-1)$ new path and one for directed path.

the result is same as real:

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. 5
5. 16
6. 65

   ===============================EDITED

   $c(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \frac{(n-2)!}{i!}=(n-2)!*\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{i!}$

   .

   This shows that's about $(2\text{≈}3)*(n-2)!$

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. OK, you have a recurrence but what's the solution of that recurrence?

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I added the real value of the recurrence function.